# passing a pointer through a function c

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to exit a while loop within a function but I don't think i'm writing the pointer correctly, c is new to me and reading examples online is confusing.

I would appreciate feed back on what I'm writing incorrectly.

```
int logOn(int *log);

int main(void)
{
    int log;
    log = 1;
    while(log = 1)
    {
        int logOn(log);
    }

    while(log = 2)
    {
        int mainMenu();
    }

    printf("\ngood bye");
}

int logOn(*par)
{
    char p;

    printf("would you like to log on (y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", &p);

    if(p="y")
    {
        par = 2;
    }
    else if(p="n");
    {
        par = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError entering command\n")
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've updated my code and fixed a lot of the errors you guys helped my identify.

now for some reason it goes through my logon loop twice if i hit a key neither 'y' or 'n'

this is what my current code looks like

## include

```
int logOn(int *log);
int mainMenu(int *log);

int main(void)
{
    int log;
    log = 1;
    while(log == 1)
    {
        (void) logOn(&log);
    }

    while(log == 2)
    {
        mainMenu(&log);
    }

    printf("\ngood bye");
}

int logOn(int *par)
{
    char p;

    printf("would you like to log on (y/n): ");
    scanf("%c", &p);

    if(p == 'y')
    {
        *par = 2;
    }
    else if(p == 'n')
    {
        *par = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError entering command\n");
    }
    return 1;
}

int mainMenu(int *par)
{
    printf("\nMain Menu\n");
    *par = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

and this is what it is out putting when i dont hit 'y' or 'n'

```
 would you like to log on (y/n): e

 Error entering command
 would you like to log on (y/n): 
 Error entering command
 would you like to log on (y/n):
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the observed program behavior that makes you think something's off. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(log = 1)
while(log = 2)
```

Wrong. In c, the `=` operator is for assignment, not comparison. You are *setting* log equal to 1 and 2 there. You want the `==` operator for comparison:

```
while(log == 1)
```

Next:

```
scanf("%s", &p);
```

Wrong. `%s` is for arrays of `char` ending in zero ('\0'). This is how c represents strings. For a single character, you want

```
scanf("%c", &p);
```

Next:

```
if(p="y")
```

You are misusing the assignment operator again. In addition, you are comparing a `p`, a `char` to `"y"`, a `char *` - char array. Double quotes are for strings, single quotes/apostrophes are for single characters. You are looking for

```
if(p == 'y')
```

Next:

```
else if(p="n");
```

Same errors as above, plus, the semicolon - `;` doesn't belong there. Suffice it to say, that should cause a compilation error on your `else` statement below. You want:

```
else if(p == 'n')
```

Next:

```
par = 2;
par = 3;
```

You are assigning integers to a pointer. You probably mean

```
*par = 2;
*par = 3;
```

Next:

```
int logOn(log);
```

should be

```
(void) logOn(&log);
```

Next:

```
int mainMenu();
```

I don't know what `mainMenu` is, but the `int` keyword makes no sense there.

Answer (score 3):

`while(log == 1)` it's `==` not `=`.

When in a while condition you write `log = 1` it simply assigns `1` to `log`. Then `while` gets `1` from the variable `log`, which is implicitly converted to `true`, which makes `while` loop infinitely.

Comment: oh wow, can't believe I've done that.
so I've written my pointers correctly then ?

Comment: "y" represent char array or string in c .. to represent single char just use 'y'. so instead of `if(p="n")` write `if(p=='n')` and instead of `if(p="y")` write `if(p=='y')`

Comment: `else if(p="n");` semicolon after `if` condition just ends the statement and it restricts the next block to be under `if` condition. So remove the semicolon `;`

Comment: `par` is the address not the value. So `par = 3;` changes the address not the value. To change value within `par` write `*par = 3`

Answer (score 3):

The parameters of your logOn function must be defined as so:

```
int logOn(int *par){//function body}
```

Also the syntax of your while condition must be as follows:

```
while(log == 1)
```

Note the double == sign. This is necessary as a single = sign will result in an infinite loop.

Furthermore when you pass in the address of a variable into a function as you have, then a * operator is required in front of it within the function body in order to deference the value at that address.

e.g

```
int logOn(int *par)
{
    printf("%p", par); //address par 
    printf("%d",*par); //value stored at address par
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: does that mean i need.
    *par = 2
instead of
    par = 2
?

Comment: If you're referring to inside the function body then yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

Some points in your program .

First, `while(log = 1)`, since your are checking if the log is equal to 1 or not, the syntax should be `while(log == 1)`
{
}

Secondly, while calling the `logOn` function, pass the address of log variable (`int logOn(&log)`;)

Third, The signature of the `int logOn(*par)` function should be int `logOn(int *par)`.

Fourth, `"y"` or `"n"` represents a string literal, if you want to use only a single character, use 'y' or 'n', that is with single quote.

Fifth, To change the value of a pointer use the de-referencing operator `*`.
Your line in the code should be

```
*par = 2;  (//Content of par equal to 2)

*par = 3;
```

Happy programming.